# Adobe Sign API - /transientDocyments

Tags: php, pdf, adobe, guzzle

This is the example adobe have in their documentation.
[image]

I have tried with Guzzle:

```
$client->request('POST', 'transientDocuments', [
'multipart' => [
    [
        'name'     => 'test',
        'contents' => fopen('pdfs/test.pdf', 'r'),
        'filename' => 'file.pdf',
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => "binary",
        ]
    ],
]
```

]);

`fopen` returns `resource(13) of type (stream)`

But every time I get `{"code":"NO_FILE_CONTENT","message":"Must provide file body"}`.

Answer (score 1):

You should write code to satisfy the following request shown in image below.

[image: Request of creating TransientDocument]
**Explanation**

When u log in with your e-sign account you will be redirected to one of the hosts (like `api.in1.echosign.com`). You need to put `File` as form-data parameter key and your file as value. You get `Mime-Type` based on file extension. In response you will get `TransientDocumentId` which can be used for the creating and sending agreements etc.

Comment: thank you, this is what I was looking for and it worked with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Was stuck with the same but realised that the parameters name and filename to be enclosed in double quotes. 
'name'     => '"File"',
'filename' => '"file.pdf"',

PS. my code is in .Net, not php